# How do I create this stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [NEWS]
(
    [ID]      INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TITLE]   VARCHAR(500) NULL,
    [CONTENT] VARCHAR(800) NULL,
    [CREATED] DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())

    PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)

CREATE TABLE [LOG]
(
    [ID]      INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ACTION]  VARCHAR(500) NULL,
    [CREATED] DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())

    PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
```

I want to do the following procedure:

I have an input parameter `@NewsId`.

STEP 1

- If `NewsId` is `NULL` : I want to save the row into the table (`NEWS`) .
- If `newsid` is defined then I want to update the row.

STEP 2

- I want to do step 1 and then save the record into a table named `LOG`.
- `INSERT INTO LOG ("Action") VALUES ("insert or update")`

How can I do these two steps using stored procedure?

How can I make one step after the successful completion and go to step 2?

Comment: Yes. I added a definition tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple sample to get you going.

```
create procedure MyProc (@NewsId int) as
Begin

   -- you should really pass these in?
   declare @title   varchar(500) = 'A title'
   declare @content varchar(800) = 'A piece of content'


   if @NewsId is null
   begin

     Begin Try 
       insert into News (Title, Content)  values (@title, @content)

       -- get the new id just inserted
       set @NewsId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

       insert into Log (Action) values ('insert')
     End Try

     Begin Catch
      .... handle error 
     end catch

   end
   else
   begin 
        update News set Title = @title, Content = @content
        where id = @NewsId
       insert into Log (Action) values ('update')

   end

end
```

from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12080/Using-TRY-CATCH-in-Transact-SQL):

```
Begin Try 
 The_Query_for_which_we_need_to_do_the_ Error_Handling 
End Try 
Begin Catch 

  If there is some error in the query within the Try block, this flow 
  will be passed to this Catch block. 

End catch
```

Comment: How can I protect that after successful insertion inserts a record into the log table?

Comment: not sure what you mean. Are looking for error handling of the insert of the news or the log?

Comment: Thank you so much! Last question. How can I do the following: Insert a row into a table (NEWS) and then inserted id save into a table log: INSERT INTO LOG (ACTION) VALUES ('NEWS ID 1');